# The end of listoffigures in laTex

Tags: latex, tex

On top of the abstract there is "ELENCO DELLE FIGURE", but i want that finished on previous page.

[image]

```
\newpage
%\thispagestyle{plain}
\markboth{Indice}{Indice}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
%%\listoftables

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{abstract.tex}
\input{capitolo1.tex}
\input{capitolo2.tex}
\input{capitolo3.tex}
\input{capitolo4.tex}
\input{capitolo5.tex}
\input{capitolo6.tex}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\input{ringraziamenti.tex}
\end{document}
```

Is there any one that could answer to this question?

Comment: The easiest would be to change the layout of this page (for example margins).

Answer (score 0):

To change the header of the page with the abstract, you can use the same trick as for your index and use `\markboth{Abstract}{Abstract}` in front of the abstract:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}


\newpage
%\thispagestyle{plain}
\markboth{Indice}{Indice}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
%%\listoftables

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\clearpage
\markboth{Abstract}{Abstract}
code for your abstract

\end{document}
```